# Detect is Chrome custom tab was closed?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, chrome-custom-tabs

How can I detect if a Chrome Custom Tab was closed? Is there any callback for this or do I have to use `onResume` etc. events of the activity launching the Chrome Custom Tab?

I've seen that there are already questions on this, however they are quite old - wondering, if there is meanwhile any new/proper way to do this (I am using Jetpack Compose, in case this matters)

Comment: Just wondering what is the use case?